# Gson JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am having error while parsing a **Json** with **Gson** into an object.
What I am trying to do is store the **latitude longitude** in the **double** variable but while parsing, I am getting an error. I try to change the class variables and the **gson** to string but still getting the same error.
The json it´s on github.

The error that i get is:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected an int but was 32.93644801 at line 7 column 22 path $.bars[0].lat
```

json data is:

```
{
    "bars":[
        {
            "name": "Antares Pichincha",
            "place_id": "ChIJOR29Pk-rt5UR0hsdFVQWpD8",
            "logo_src": "antares",
            "lat": -32.936448000001,
            "lng": -60.6587110
        }
    ]
}
```

and the class reciving the data is

```
public class BarList {

    //@SerializedName("bars")
    List<Bar> bars;

    public List<Bar> getBars(){
        return bars;
    }
}

public class Bar {

    private String name;
    private String place_id;
    private String logo_src;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    public Bar(String name, String place_id, String logo_src, double lat, double lng) {
        this.name = name;
        this.place_id = place_id;
        this.logo_src = logo_src;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }
```

and here is where I call it

```
GsonRequest<BarList> request = new GsonRequest<BarList>(
                JSON_URL,
                BarList.class,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<BarList>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(BarList response) {
                        barList = response;
                        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error Respuesta en JSON: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        );
```

Someone have any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: could you show where are you accessing this `Bar.lat`? Where are you converting to gson?

Comment: try to put value as a string and then convert it to double when you want to use it

Comment: Show some more code, the place where the error occurs especially...

Comment: I tried to parse this with simple gson.fromJson and it worked, so I guess more code like Vucko suggested would be nice.

Comment: Later I need the lat and lng to store it in a LatLng element for a marker in a googlemap objetc.

Comment: Vucko the error shows up on the ErrorListener.

At the moment I change the code to get it as a Strign but the parser keep saying that expects an int

Comment: Have you tried understanding what the error that you have mentioned says? It clearly says that the following is looking for **int** but has been given double to it, thus you are getting the following error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether thats your problem, but your bars array contains just a single element but in line 9 is a comma which should be followed by another element.

Comment: I tried it, it's just creating an empty list item then.

Comment: Yes sorry just copy firs element of the json to show as an example

Answer (score 0):

I ask to a developer friend to take a look at the code and he could not find any problems or errors  on the code, so he told me to delete the installed app on the device and re-build the project and that solve the issue.

Thanks everyone for the answers.